# Erro ao gerar o build de aplicativo IOS no IONIC

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Estou tentando fazer o build de um aplicativo IOS no Ionic.

Rodei no terminal: `ionic cordova build ios --release --prod`

Mas estou recebendo:

> build-release.xcconfig line 28: Unable to find included file "../pods-release.xcconfig"** BUILD FAILED **

Naveguei ate esse arquivo build-release.xcconfig e encontrei na linha 28 o seguinte import:

```
#include "../pods-release.xcconfig"
```

Procurei no meu projeto mas não o encontrei. Em qual processo é gerado esse arquivo?

Pra instalar o cocoapods no meu projeto eu segui os passos:

Naveguei ate a pasta platforms/ios e rodei:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup

pod init

pod install
```

Então rodei o build e tive esse erro de não encontrar o arquivo...

Comment: Você está rodando esse comando em um terminal no Mac ?

Comment: @ViniciusLourenço sim

Comment: Verifique se, no xcode, nas configurações você está com o `Build System` setado para `Legacy Build System`. Você pode experimentar rodar o comando `ionic cordova platform rm ios` para remover o iOS e adicione de novo com `ionic cordova platform add ios`, isso normalmente resolve quaisquer problemas com o build.